# how to get the signal name in the prompt

Tags: signals, command-prompt, zsh

I have my zsh prompt configured to display a different prompt depending on whether the exit status of the last command was zero or nonzero, with

```
# Pimp my prompt.
PS1="%{${ESC}[38;5;204m%}%n%{$reset%}"                # Username
PS1="$PS1@%{${ESC}[38;5;104m%m$reset%}"               # @Machine
PS1="$PS1:%{${ESC}[38;5;78m%}%~%{$reset%}"            # :Directory
PS1="$PS1$NL%(0?,,%{${ESC}[38;5;0m${ESC}[48;5;162m%}%?%{$reset%} )" # Status
PS1="$PS1%(#.#.$) "                                   # Prompt
```

Now I am wondering if I can make the prompt contain the signal name if the exit status is > 128, i.e. for 129 contain `HUP` for 130 `INT` etc. The list of signals on my system is (in increasing signal number from 1 to 32 <=> exit status 129 to 160):

```
$ kill -l
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH INFO USR1 USR2 THR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, although you'll need to customize it slightly for your prompt.

```
get_exit_code() {
    # Grab the last exit status. 
    VALUE=$?

    if [[ VALUE -eq 0 ]]; then
        # Don't display anything if we got a clean exit code.
        echo ""
    else
        # Get the name of the exit code, then return.
        NAME=`kill -l ${VALUE}`
        echo "${NAME}"
    fi
}

# Use the function in our prompt.
export PROMPT=$'$ $(get_exit_code) '
```

Here's a sample output from my system:

```
$
$  return 3
$ QUIT return 129
$ HUP return 2
$ INT
```

Comment: Note: I had to change my config to include `setopt promptsubst` so PS1 would undergo command substitution.

Comment: FWIW, the code is missing a `$` sign at the if conditional: `if [[ $VALUE ...`

Comment: @Francisco The code works as posted, though - the `$` doesn't appear to be necessary. This can be verified by putting a word into the echo statement in that conditional branch, which will only be output after an exit status of 0. I don't know why the `$` isn't needed.